# How to make brightness and contrast settings adaptive for a thermal camera for data consistency?

Tags: image-processing, camera, computer-vision, brightness, contrast

Context: We are using a thermal camera to detect and classify objects passing in-front of the camera. The detection is for 24 hours throughout the day. We use sensoray to grab frames from the thermal camera and opencv for image processing. Platform is windows and we use c++.

Problem:
If we keep the brightness and contrast settings same throughout the day the features observed for the object changes ( as the object is hotter during the day ) which affects our deep learning models. So I wanted to know about any methods which can observe certain simple features in an image ( like histogram ) and determine that brightness and contrast needs to be changed ( and also by how much ).

Picture with appropriate contrast ( you can see features in the wheel ):

[image]

Picture with bad contrast ( no features visible )

[image]

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you provided day and night sample images and said what platform, language, operating system and tools you use.

Comment: If your problem can be solved by only adjusting contrast and brightness like you assume, you could normalize them by clipping unused brightness levels. I don't think your problem is that easy based on your description but without a sample there's really no way to tell. I would expect a CNN to be able to learn different thermal distributions though.

Comment: Hi, I have added the sample images for your references